# nohup bash myscript.sh > log.log yeilds empty file until the process is stopped manually

Tags: bash, logging, nohup

I have a python file that I run using a .sh file providing some args. When I run this file on the terminal using `bash myscript.sh` it runs fine, prints progress on the console. When I use nohup like `nohup bash myscript.sh > log.log` nothing gets saved to log.log file but the processes are running (it's a 4 GPU process and I can see the GPU usage in top and nvidia-smi). As soon as I kill the process using either ctrl+c or kill command, all the output gets printed to the file at once along with keyboard interrupt or process killed message.
I have tried `nohup myscript.sh &> log.log` `nohup myscript.sh &>> log.log` but the issue remains the same. What's the reason for such a behaviour?

myscript.sh runs a python file somewhat like

```
python main.py --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2
```

I tried

```
python -u main.py
```

but it doesn't help. I know the script is working fine as it occupies exactly same amount of memory as it should.

Comment: Maybe a buffering issue? Without knowing what's in the script, it's impossible to do more than guess. Can you strip the script down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. simplify the script so it's as close as possible to `echo start; sleep 60; echo end` while still showing the problem) and add that to your question?

Comment: @GordonDavisson the script runs a python file providing some arguments. I tried adding -u after python but it still remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stdbuf:

```
nohup stdbuf -oL bash myscript.sh > log.log
```

Your problem is related to output buffering. In general, non-interactive output to files tend to be block buffered. The `-oL` changes output buffering to line mode. There is also the less efficient `-o0` to change it to unbuffered.